# Pasar un puntero de tipo estructura a una funcion por intermedio de Gtk

Tags: c, gtk, widget

Yo cree una estructura y reserve memoria:

```
stc_control* stc_control_0 = (stc_control*) malloc (sizeof (stc_control*) * 5);
```

y quiero que otra funcion reciba esta estructura, asi que se la paso por esta funcion de widget:

```
g_signal_connect_swapped (spin_1, "value-changed", nombre_funcion, stc_control_0);
```

y en la funcion: nombre_funcion quedo de esta forma

```
void nombre_funcion (GtkWidget* widget, gpointer gp) { ... }
```

El problema que no he podido solucionar es el siguiente:

```
Problema presentado en esta funcion: `nombre_funcion`: advertencia: desreferenciando puntero `void *`
(*gp).atritubo_en_estructura = __dame_el_valor_del_widget__y_guardalo_en_atriuto__;

error: solicitud de miembro ‘atributo_en_estructura’ en algo que no es una estructura o union
(*gp).atritubo_en_estructura = __dame_el_valor_del_widget__y_guardalo_en_atriuto__;
```

Que signfica esto de desreferenciar?

Answer (score 1):

1. `sizeof (stc_control*)` está mal, quieres `sizeof (stc_control)` (sin el asterisco). Necesitas una estructura, ¡no un puntero!
2. `gp` es un puntero `gpointer` alias `void*`, necesitas una converción:

   ```
   stc_control* control = gp;
   // o: stc_control* control = (stc_control*)gp;
   control->atritubo_en_estructura = ...
   ```
3. Siempre escribir `puntero->campo`, ¡nunca `(*puntero).campo`!

Comment: Realice los cambios y quedaron de la siguiente manera:

`stc_control* stc_control_0 = (stc_control*) malloc (sizeof (stc_control) * 5);`

Al llamar a la funcion esta queda:

`stc_control* data = (stc_control *) gd;`

`data->atributo = 77.77;`
`// o: (*data).atributo = 77.77;`

Compila sin errores y a poner a prueba la funcion: 

`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: @HumbertoSantiagoMolinaresPa Para resolver eso, necesitaría más código (un programa completo).

Comment: Gracias por la colaboracion. La verdad no te entiendo. Tu no necesitas el codigo completo solamente vas a necesitar el concepto que se este trabajando y por el cual se consulta para asesoria. Gracias

Comment: @HumbertoSantiagoMolinaresPa Necesitas mostrar un [mcve]. A veces es posible resolver con menos de eso, y a veces no.

Answer (score 0):

Trata de utilizar todas las sobrecargas de funciones ofrecidas por GLib(Base fundamental de GTK), es aconsejable utilizar [g_malloc](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Memory-Allocation.html#g-malloc), ya que esta saca el programa de su flujo normal y lo termina si no es capaz de asignar memoria al puntero.

malloc pide un tamaño en Byte para asignarlo en memoria y retorna un puntero generico a esa dirección; `NULL` en caso de no poder asignar memoria. Al hacer `sizeof (stc_control*) * 5` supongo que quieres asignar memoria para un Array de tipo `stc_control` de 5 posiciones, pero lo que realmente estas haciendo es asignar un Array de *punteros* de tipo `stc_control` de 5 posiciones; si quieres la primera debes cambiarlo por `sizeof (stc_control) * 5`.

Una observación no relacionada con tu código. `gpointer` no es más que un alias `typedef void* gpointer` utilizado para suavizar  la sintaxis C que suele volverse confunza con mucha facilidad. Al ser un puntero generico debes tener en cuenta que solo le puedes asignar variables y no literales, en este sentido se debe tener mucho cuidado con muchas funcionalidades de GLib que realmente son macros y no funcionan con literales(la documentación de GLib pide encarecidamente tener cuidado con esos casos).